# How to reduce response time from Amazon S3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, datadog

I have java method that gets last saved file from S3 bucket by getting list of all objects and sorting them by name (all files has timestamp in their name). The problem is that response time could be 13 seconds and up to 20, depends on how many objects in the bucket [image]

I guess problem lies in call rout - client - cloudflare - loadbalancer - ingress controler - my service container  - ingress controler - loadbalancer - cloudflare - client, because when I call this method from localhost, response time is 1.5 ms in avarage

Is there a way to reduce response time?

Service method

```
public URL getLastSavedFile(Integer vehicleId) {
    try {
        S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary = repository.downloadLastFile(String.valueOf(vehicleId));
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = getPresignedUrl(s3ObjectSummary);
        log.info("Returned URL of last file from S3 storage, for vehicle - {}", vehicleId);
        return s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(request);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        log.info("Failed to get last snapshot, the following - {} doesn't exist in storage", vehicleId);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public S3ObjectSummary downloadLastFile(String vehicleId) {
    ObjectListing listing = s3client.listObjects( env.getProperty("INIT_S3_BUCKET"), vehicleId );
    List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = listing.getObjectSummaries();
    while (listing.isTruncated()) {
        listing = s3client.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
        objects.addAll (listing.getObjectSummaries());
    }
    objects.sort((o1, o2) -> o2.getKey().compareTo(o1.getKey()));
    return objects.get(0); //sorted list with most recent timestamp in the beginning
}
```

UPD:

**FIXED!** It appers that all problems were due to the maven dependencies, I had old version 1.12.382 of aws-java-sdk and when I change it to version 1.12.415 of aws-java-sdk-s3 - it fixed the problem and now response time is 1-2 seconds

Comment: I'd say that the route might add a few 100 ms but not several seconds. I'd suspect that's related to factors like size of the data (which might hit some bandwidth limit) and storage class (i.e. cheaper cold storage in S3 would take longer to query) among other things. Having a look at the [S3 performance guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance-guidelines.html) might help.

Comment: This is a case where adding a couple lines of logging to your code will be much better than having strangers on the Internet guess at causes. Log when you start `downloadLastFile()` and at the end, _with the count of objects retrieved_. If that doesn't account for your time, move up a level.

Comment: `listObjects` requires multiple serial API calls to S3, at least one per 1000 files.  For large enough buckets, that will take considerable time.  If getting slightly older lists is acceptable, setting up an [S3 Inventory Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) can speed things up.  If not, consider setting up a [metadata database](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-maintaining-an-amazon-s3-metadata-index-without-servers/) to have a quick database query available instead of a brute force list.

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks for propose, I'll try to use metadata, but I don't think that problem in bucket size, because even if my bucket has only 5 files (jpg) and size of each file in avarage 30 kb - it still has response time 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!
It appers that all problems were due to the maven dependencies, I had old version 1.12.382 of aws-java-sdk and when I change it to version 1.12.415 of aws-java-sdk-s3 - it fixed the problem and now response time is 1-2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

1.5ms vs 15 seconds is A LOT :D

There are at least 2 approach to improve the response time of S3:

1. Use [Transfer Acceleration](https://aws.amazon.com/it/s3/transfer-acceleration/). Improves both uploads and downloads, uses edge locations to route your request trough AWS internal infrastructure.
2. Use [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/secure-content-delivery-amazon-cloudfront/s3-origin-with-cloudfront.html). Improves just downloads, uses edge locations to cache your content.